# Cannot connect React (react-router) with back-end Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

So, I have an application with a React front-end and Express back-end that are hosted on different ports, `0.0.0.0:3000` (React) and `0.0.0.0:6969` (Express).

How do I ensure all `/api/v1` requests are routed to the Express instead of going to my preset `PageNotFound` page?

I am trying to allow users to send requests `0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/{request}`  instead of using `0.0.0.0:6969/{request}`

Is this possible?

front-end/index.js:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="userpage" element={<UserPage />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<PageDoesntExist />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

front-end/package.json:

```
...
"proxy":"http://0.0.0.0:6969",
...
```

back-end/index.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const { app, version } = require('./app');
const server = http.createServer(app);

const port = process.env.PORT || 6969;
const ip = '0.0.0.0';
app.set('port', port);
//app.use('/api', app);

server.listen(port, ip, () => {
    const address = server.address();
    const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : ip + ':' + port + '/api/v' + version;
    console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
});
```

I thought that doing the proxy and removing the `PageDoesntExist` element would solve the problem but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to `"/api/v1"` in the frontend? Backend APIs don't have much of anything to do with frontend routing/navigation. What exactly are you doing? Can you [edit] the post to include where you are trying to make API requests to the backend? See [mcve].

Comment: Apologies, are the current edits easier to understand?

Comment: Oh, I see. You could configure the backend to listen/handle requests on `"/api/v1"` and redirect/return the React app's `index.html` for all other requests. OFC the backend would then also need to be running on port 3000. That said, I don't know if there's much to gain in doing so. What is serving the React app currently if it isn't your backend code?

Comment: So I wouldn’t need to run the react start script and server start script separately right? I don’t understand express that well, sorry.

Comment: The react app currently is a website, and the backend is the API to the database.

Comment: It depends on your plans for the production architecture of the project. For example,  I like to keep the React apps on a separate subdomain to the Express api. This helps with performance and caching. e.g. I have an AWS bucket to deliver the React app at `mydomain.com`, and Express is separate at `api.mydomain.com`. In this configuration, I use a series of env config files and environment variables to point to the backend (either local dev or live production). To develop locally, I have the standard React dev server on port 3000 and Express on 3001.

Comment: I agree that the separations of concerns between hosting/serving the frontend separate from hosting/handling backend APIs/DBs is likely to be considered more optimal by most.